# How to create a 2D string array out of bunch of regular arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a bunch of regular arrays each of them contains only 2 elements. I want to add them up to make one 2D array

```
            String[] sigleArray = getArray1(); String[] sigleArray2 = getArray2(); String[] sigleArray3 = getArray3(); // ... etc getting them from a different method
            ArrayList<String[]> arraysList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            arraysList.add(sigleArray);
            arraysList.add(sigleArray2);
            arraysList.add(sigleArray3);
            // etc .............
            String[][] finalArray = arraysList.toArray(new String[arraysList.size()][2]);
```

It does not compile. Eclipse underlines `arraysList.add(sigleArray);`

Message is

[image]

Comment: How do you want to do that?  Show us your expected result.

Comment: It does not compile. Eclipse underlines arraysList.add(sigleArray); with what message?  You code as you've pasted it won't compile because your arrays (in which you've misspelt single) are never instantiated.

Comment: The error message in Eclipse will clearly tell you what the reason is:  the arrays are never instantiated

Comment: I am getting the arrays dynamically from a different method and class

Comment: The error message mentions a variable named 'claim' which it thinks is a string, not a string array, but your example code has no such variable.  Your example code would appear not to match the code responsible for the message you have posted.

Comment: Why am I not getting an errors with this exact code (I just initialized arrays)

Comment: @Rafaello What is the type of 'claim' ? It says that is a String, not a String [].

Comment: RAFAELLO, listen up man.  You need to post the code where you try to add the 'claim' to the array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized your arrays.  You have only defined them.

```
String[] singleArray = new String[size];

String[] singleArray = {"", "", ""}
```

Comment: This is not the problem. In reality I am getting these array from a method

Comment: Then your code example doesn't really show the problem then, does it?  Show the method you are getting it from.  It likely returns a String instead of String[].

Comment: I apologize. I have modified it

Comment: No you haven't.  Show the claim variable, it's type, and where you are getting it from.